# Some bootstrap3 glyphicons not work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

when I use "pushpin":

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></span>
```

It works fine.
but when I want use "glyphicon-menu-right" it doesn't work:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span>
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin is in **3.3.1 version** which has the same version as `glyphicon chevron-right` that you should use, **not** `glyphicon-menu-right` since glyphicon-menu-right is in **3.3.2 version**.

Not all old versions removed when updated, but some of them. when you find new glyphicon icon, you should see if the version is not against your current version.

The solution is: 
check your bootstrap version. If you use 3.3.2 version there will be no problem with that. I think you use 3.3.1 version.
[image]

tutorial for 3.3.2 version where you find both glyphicons, see [**here**](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-icons.php)